# Measure punch power by calculate distance and speed of iphone

Tags: ios

I want to measure the punch power by iphone, and I think I need to measure the distance iphone move from starting point to the end point, I measure time for this movement.
I can calculate speed = distance / time
I need the mass of user's body, I can know the mass of user's arm
From the speed and the mass of user's arm, I can calculate the punch power (Newton unit)

Did I think right? Or have any method that I don't know? 
Should I use Accelerator or GPS to measure?

Thanks

Comment: People making a punching motion as hard as they can with a phone in their hand seems like a bad idea.

Comment: And the GPS is not going to be accurate enough to measure movements of a couple feet.

Comment: Accelerometer sounds like a good idea, but it would be much better to attach the phone to a punching bag and use the mass of the bag to figure out the impulse.

Comment: Sound like a good idea for android devices...